# How to dismiss temporary view when tap in UISearchDisplayController's SearchBar in iOS?

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

You know , when we tap into UISearchBar of UISearchDisplayController, the black temp view will appear that hide our view with low opacity.

I want to remove that temp view when tap UISearchBar.
Is there anyway to remove that view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone? I need help.

Comment: were you able to do this? am having the same issue

Comment: I am okay with this problem.I used this with trick. Use Hidden Property of UISearchDisplayController's ResultTableView to YES or NO. That's will fix. :)